# Add a path after / to http request in HAProxxy

Tags: rewrite, haproxy, 301-redirect

I am currently redirecting my users from get.foo.com to foodownload.com, and then they can click and download bar.mp4. I want before redirecting, change the path, so by entering get.foo.com, their url rewrites to foodownload.com/bar.mp4.
my redirection line is:

```
redirect prefix foodownload.com code 301 if is_get_foo_com
```

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
acl get_foo_com hdr(host) -i get.foo.com
http-request redirect location http://foodownload.com/bar.mp4 code 301 if get_foo_com
```

What this does:

1. Checks the provided host against `get.foo.com`; evaluates to `TRUE` or `FALSE`.
2. Redirects the client via `301 Moved permanently` to `http://foodownload.com/bar.mp4` if `get_foo_com` is `TRUE`.

For more information and background, check out the docs for [ACLs](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.6.html#7) and [redirects](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.6.html#redirect).

Comment: I Tried that. problem is when the http host is modified, it puts a / automatically after that. so It becomes foodownload.com/bar.mp4/ and shows 404

Comment: Doesn't happen for me with this code. Could you show the complete code you've tried?

Comment: @FarhadGh If you're interested, I could send you the headers I'm getting with above code...or just try it yourself, it works as expected. Please note: I'm using `http-request redirect...`, your code just had `redirect...`.